# ng-keypress="return press($event,'text')" return not working

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to return value in ng-keypress event. Idea is to prevent few characters being pressed. I Know I can do the same without returning true/false by event.preventdefault().

ng-keypress="return press($event,'text')" not working

```
scope.press = function(event)
{
  event = (event) ? event : window.event;
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) || charCode==8 ) 
   {
        return;
   }
   else 
  { 
    return false;
  }
 }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Where is the `press()` function? Why is there a return statement in the expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this directive

```
.directive('preventKey', function ($timeout, Ls) {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

        element.bind('keydown', function (e, inputs) {

            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            var val = element[0].value;

            var current = document.activeElement;
         //Enter all Charcodes u want where u want to prevent keypress
            if (code === 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

In your Html you use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="something" preventKey>
```